# How to plot an average line with Standard Deviation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code gives me the average of 2 lines and the Standard Deviation. I am not sure though whether it calculates the Standard Deviation from each row of the 2 variables or it calculates it from one common X value for both variables. I want it to be the later one. In my full data the X axis of both values is normalised from 0-100. However, as you can see the x value on the 1st variable is slightly different from the 2nd, and it also has missing values. My aim is to be able to plot an average line of the 2, being calculated from a common x value for both variables and also the average line to show ± SD. Anyone can help me with this? Thank you in advance.
'''

```
setwd()
library(ggplot2)

test = read.csv("foldername.csv")

library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

newdat <- data.table::melt(as.data.table(test),
                           measure = patterns("^distance","^grey"),
                           value.name = c("distance", "grey"))

newdat

test$mean <- (test$grey1 + test$grey2) / 2
test$d <- (test$distance1 + test$distance2) / 2
test$sd <- unlist(Map(function(a, b) sd(c(a, b)), test$grey1, test$grey2))

ggplot(newdat) +
  geom_line(aes(distance, grey, color = variable)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = test, aes(d, ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),
              alpha = 0.15) +
  geom_line(data = test, aes(d, mean, color = "Avg")) +
  geom_point(data = test, aes(d, mean)) +
  geom_point(aes(distance, grey)) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16)
```

Comment: This is very similar to your last question, where I showed how to get the standard deviation for each row of your data frame, plotted at the mean of their x variables. I am very dubious about your method here. You have two trend lines that each have only a small variance around their trend lines, and pointwise standard deviation seems a very poor way of describing this data - it's statistically problematic. Are you sure this is what you want to do? If so, what was wrong with the answer to your last question? Perhaps more explanation of what you are trying to show will get a better answer?

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I replied to the previous answer of yours too in my previous question. So, I would wish for the SD to be calculated from a specific X value for both variables and not from each row if that is possible. My data are a lot larger with a lot more variables, but I tried to include a small example here.

Comment: But it looks like your data is made of several linear series. Would your standard deviation not be better modelled as treating your series as random effects?

Comment: Yes I agree. Do you have a suggestion on that?

Comment: Could you post an extra couple of your variables to allow a reasonable regression?

Comment: I posted as answer my 3 variables with all the values for the x axis ranging from 0-100 (normalised). So, for this data I wish to be plotting an average line (I believe the right thing to do here is to take a common x value for all the variables and not do the mean across each row as the x values are not the same across each row). And along with the average line to show also the standard deviation. Could you help me with that? Thank you a lot. @AllanCameron

Comment: Please don't do that. If you add something to the question, add it to the question. - Others will confuse questions and answer which will limit the usefulness of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
distance1   gray1       distance2   grey2       distance3   grey3
0           1042.785    0           1044.665    0           1200.192
0.195386947 1039.821    0.227877345 1053.033    0.234281375 1212.334
0.390773894 1041.813    0.455754691 1058.786    0.46856275  1217.542
0.585860708 1037.697    0.683281994 1056.7      0.702484246 1215.882
0.781247655 1043.458    0.911159339 1063.985    0.936765621 1217.297
0.976634602 1040.869    1.139036684 1071.012    1.171046997 1220.952
1.17202155  1045.371    1.36691403  1067.917    1.405328372 1214.435
1.367108363 1048.531    1.594441333 1068.959    1.639249868 1206.786
1.56249531  1046.701    1.822318678 1071.712    1.873531243 1214.916
1.757882258 1046.911    2.050196024 1073.503    2.107812618 1227.63
1.953269205 1048.985    2.278073369 1071.605    2.342093993 1228.631
2.148356018 1042.638    2.505600672 1076.041    2.576015489 1222.493
2.343742966 1048.493    2.733478017 1071.618    2.810296864 1225.806
2.539129913 1050.859    2.961355363 1077.015    3.04457824  1234.175
2.73451686  1049.103    3.189232708 1085.241    3.278859615 1231.391
2.929603674 1048.691    3.416760011 1089.369    3.512781111 1240.373
3.124990621 1051.555    3.644637356 1088.564    3.747062486 1247.924
3.320377568 1052.885    3.872514702 1086.538    3.981343861 1244.93
3.515764515 1048.694    4.100392047 1097.495    4.215625236 1252.445
3.710851329 1046.575    4.32791935  1096.249    4.449546732 1248.823
3.906238276 1048.734    4.555796696 1097.516    4.683828107 1255.153
4.101625223 1047.27     4.783674041 1093.409    4.918109482 1255.064
4.29701217  1045.747    5.011551386 1093.76     5.152390858 1254.582
4.492098984 1048.787    5.239078689 1097.244    5.386312354 1264.992
4.687485931 1047.795    5.466956035 1094.916    5.620593729 1260.951
4.882872878 1055.342    5.69483338  1094.181    5.854875104 1258.917
5.078259826 1052.105    5.922710725 1110.82     6.089156479 1271.708
5.273346639 1059.567    6.150238029 1104.228    6.323077975 1264.552
5.468733586 1060.937    6.378115374 1104.371    6.55735935  1256.417
5.664120534 1053.673    6.605992719 1100.831    6.791640725 1260.252
5.859507481 1055.474    6.833870064 1100.399    7.025922101 1256.935
6.054594294 1055.06     7.061397368 1104.706    7.259843596 1269.913
6.249981242 1062.142    7.289274713 1105.707    7.494124972 1258.87
6.445368189 1057.556    7.517152058 1102.611    7.728406347 1263.644
6.640755136 1060.193    7.745029404 1108.61     7.962687722 1265.441
6.83584195  1056.597    7.972556707 1112.92     8.196609218 1260.239
7.031228897 1067.107    8.200434052 1113.085    8.430890593 1266.42
7.226615844 1062.53     8.428311397 1115.292    8.665171968 1267.115
7.422002791 1064.208    8.656188743 1110.612    8.899453343 1261.555
7.617089605 1068.159    8.883716046 1110.147    9.133374839 1273.59
7.812476552 1068.63     9.111593391 1114.918    9.367656215 1270.774
8.007863499 1071.127    9.339470736 1113.384    9.60193759  1261.617
8.203250446 1069.542    9.567348082 1111.732    9.836218965 1263.81
8.39833726  1070.19     9.794875385 1109.679    10.07014046 1266.964
8.593724207 1079.781    10.02275273 1109.003    10.30442184 1268.929
8.789111154 1075.442    10.25063008 1114.957    10.53870321 1261.915
8.984498102 1072.463    10.47850742 1120.371    10.77298459 1273.484
9.179584915 1076.578    10.70603472 1120.071    11.00690608 1272.091
9.374971862 1076.262    10.93391207 1122.063    11.24118746 1267.805
9.57035881  1080.995    11.16178941 1124.497    11.47546883 1268.162
9.765745757 1080.967    11.38966676 1135.618    11.70975021 1268.836
9.96083257  1081.731    11.61719406 1136.011    11.9436717  1271.251
10.15621952 1091.051    11.84507141 1123.679    12.17795308 1265.521
10.35160646 1085.902    12.07294875 1135.364    12.41223445 1260.88
10.54699341 1087.284    12.3008261  1142.031    12.64651583 1259.269
10.74208023 1101.745    12.5283534  1136.739    12.88043733 1264.392
10.93746717 1097.782    12.75623075 1135.531    13.1147187  1267.703
11.13285412 1102.222    12.98410809 1144.287    13.34900008 1260.322
11.32824107 1099.452    13.21198544 1146.434    13.58328145 1259.842
11.52332788 1106.742    13.43951274 1145.084    13.81720295 1262.868
11.71871483 1106.248    13.66739009 1148.82     14.05148432 1265.225
11.91410178 1113.173    13.89526743 1148.494    14.2857657  1272.55
12.10948872 1110.402    14.12314478 1160.856    14.52004707 1270.038
12.30457554 1121.621    14.35067208 1159.72     14.75396857 1275.29
12.49996248 1118.431    14.57854943 1164.241    14.98824994 1278.44
12.69534943 1121.764    14.80642677 1162.461    15.22253132 1277.094
12.89073638 1126.576    15.03430412 1169.802    15.45681269 1276.44
13.08582319 1130.101    15.26183142 1164.974    15.69073419 1286.831
13.28121014 1140.481    15.48970877 1168.441    15.92501556 1291.644
13.47659709 1140.594    15.71758611 1168.935    16.15929694 1298.652
13.67198403 1147.892    15.94546346 1164.132    16.39357832 1295.963
13.86707085 1151.127    16.17299076 1175.286    16.62749981 1292.062
14.06245779 1164.337    16.4008681  1171.964    16.86178119 1293.062
14.25784474 1163.867    16.62874545 1177.042    17.09606256 1299.555
14.45323169 1176.062    16.85662279 1178.729    17.33034394 1293.133
14.6483185  1179.273    17.0841501  1178.849    17.56426543 1289.666
14.84370545 1184.558    17.31202744 1189.056    17.79854681 1300.859
15.0390924  1199.634    17.53990479 1179.348    18.03282818 1306.159
15.23447934 1202.2      17.76778213 1178.475    18.26710956 1295.766
15.42956616 1212.207    17.99530944 1181.635    18.50103105 1305.796
15.6249531  1215.651    18.22318678 1185.596    18.73531243 1308.884
15.82034005 1220.462    18.45106413 1185.594    18.9695938  1306.153
16.015727   1225.722    18.67894147 1187.991    19.20387518 1304.794
16.21081381 1238.398    18.90646878 1193.549    19.43779668 1304.268
16.40620076 1240.127    19.13434612 1183.931    19.67207805 1304.158
16.60158771 1242.841    19.36222347 1177.376    19.90635943 1311.717
16.79697465 1255.348    19.59010081 1187.719    20.1406408  1302.97
16.99206147 1255.422    19.81762812 1194.028    20.3745623  1299.852
17.18744841 1257.395    20.04550546 1196.38     20.60884367 1306.7
17.38283536 1254.955    20.27338281 1199.424    20.84312505 1299.812
17.57822231 1261.917    20.50126015 1191.503    21.07740642 1305.75
17.77330912 1259.959    20.72878745 1197.416    21.31132792 1309.79
17.96869607 1262.609    20.9566648  1200.042    21.54560929 1306.776
18.16408302 1261.415    21.18454215 1196.512    21.77989067 1302.339
18.35946996 1265.141    21.41241949 1204.008    22.01417204 1312.566
18.55455678 1270.111    21.63994679 1208.454    22.24809354 1308.931
18.74994372 1283.496    21.86782414 1206.104    22.48237491 1306.14
18.94533067 1280.073    22.09570148 1202.004    22.71665629 1298.986
19.14071762 1276.348    22.32357883 1209.411    22.95093767 1298.414
19.33580443 1276.538    22.55110613 1217.433    23.18485916 1305.019
19.53119138 1280.927    22.77898348 1211.858    23.41914054 1304.943
19.72657833 1278.517    23.00686082 1212.866    23.65342191 1303.843
19.92196527 1273.389    23.23473817 1219.386    23.88770329 1312.771
20.11705209 1265.021    23.46226547 1211.222    24.12162478 1312.889
20.31243904 1270.686    23.69014282 1214.322    24.35590616 1300.83
20.50782598 1271.871    23.91802016 1205.37     24.59018753 1303.399
20.70321293 1270.333    24.14589751 1207.617    24.82446891 1296.856
20.89829974 1266.767    24.37342481 1207.627    25.0583904  1313.285
21.09368669 1270.221    24.60130216 1202.03     25.29267178 1316.43
21.28907364 1261.229    24.8291795  1202.048    25.52695315 1319.065
21.48446058 1264.154    25.05705685 1211.856    25.76123453 1319.923
21.6795474  1265.315    25.28458415 1216.535    25.99515603 1323.764
21.87493435 1259.762    25.5124615  1218.574    26.2294374  1331.434
22.07032129 1250.067    25.74033884 1214.723    26.46371878 1331.983
22.26570824 1248.453    25.96821619 1220.235    26.69800015 1333.196
22.46079505 1258.728    26.19574349 1222.794    26.93192165 1329.207
22.656182   1263.645    26.42362083 1217.513    27.16620302 1339.686
22.85156895 1263.428    26.65149818 1214.087    27.4004844  1332.976
23.0469559  1266.516    26.87937553 1225.965    27.63476577 1327.948
23.24204271 1268.666    27.10690283 1235.721    27.86868727 1325.549
23.43742966 1255.853    27.33478017 1229.547    28.10296864 1328.612
23.6328166  1259.221    27.56265752 1231.347    28.33725002 1330.375
23.82820355 1261.574    27.79053486 1234.503    28.57153139 1325.951
24.02329036 1270.838    28.01806217 1230.809    28.80545289 1330.339
24.21867731 1273.371    28.24593951 1237.396    29.03973427 1327.25
24.41406426 1269.835    28.47381686 1236.809    29.27401564 1330.634
24.60945121 1266.713    28.7016942  1241.027    29.50829702 1320.868
24.80453802 1275.839    28.92922151 1240.808    29.74221851 1321.274
24.99992497 1274.524    29.15709885 1237.861    29.97649989 1322.013
25.19531191 1273.947    29.3849762  1244.811    30.21078126 1324.63
25.39069886 1273.316    29.61285354 1256.42     30.44506264 1322.006
25.58578567 1270.673    29.84038085 1255.099    30.67898413 1326.767
25.78117262 1272.068    30.06825819 1258.272    30.91326551 1318.591
25.97655957 1276.38     30.29613554 1262.526    31.14754688 1319.324
26.17194652 1274.375    30.52401288 1256.864    31.38182826 1323.928
26.36703333 1269.057    30.75154018 1259.304    31.61574975 1321.33
26.56242028 1278.399    30.97941753 1266.155    31.85003113 1319.697
26.75780722 1279.283    31.20729488 1264.378    32.0843125  1322.651
26.95319417 1286.107    31.43517222 1260.529    32.31859388 1329.691
27.14828099 1288.766    31.66269952 1259.727    32.55251538 1330.029
27.34366793 1284.196    31.89057687 1257.918    32.78679675 1335.289
27.53905488 1276.177    32.11845421 1261.104    33.02107813 1337.297
27.73444183 1280.679    32.34633156 1264.63     33.2553595  1330.079
27.92952864 1277.787    32.57385886 1262.937    33.489281   1335.586
28.12491559 1283.116    32.80173621 1266.648    33.72356237 1340.431
28.32030253 1284.408    33.02961355 1260.039    33.95784375 1346.398
28.51568948 1275.073    33.2574909  1257.602    34.19212512 1347.401
28.71107643 1275.578    33.48536824 1245.593    34.4264065  1345.878
28.90616324 1280.876    33.71289555 1259.246    34.66032799 1337.836
29.10155019 1280.23     33.94077289 1263.294    34.89460937 1334.334
29.29693714 1272.904    34.16865024 1258.028    35.12889074 1331.395
29.49232408 1277.38     34.39652758 1258.524    35.36317212 1324.142
29.6874109  1270.53     34.62405489 1259.911    35.59709362 1326.864
29.88279785 1269.179    34.85193223 1263.922    35.83137499 1329.095
30.07818479 1270.867    35.07980958 1269.997    36.06565637 1325.685
30.27357174 1267.747    35.30768692 1269.89     36.29993774 1325.067
30.46865855 1268.156    35.53521423 1269.676    36.53385924 1319.241
30.6640455  1262.504    35.76309157 1279.297    36.76814061 1317.559
30.85943245 1270.514    35.99096892 1276.366    37.00242199 1316.047
31.05481939 1262.134    36.21884626 1270.392    37.23670336 1316.642
31.24990621 1267.405    36.44637356 1275.914    37.47062486 1308.388
31.44529316 1271.278    36.67425091 1267.72     37.70490623 1311.707
31.6406801  1266.706    36.90212826 1271.408    37.93918761 1308.14
31.83606705 1267.077    37.1300056  1273.148    38.17346898 1307.796
32.03115386 1260.824    37.3575329  1276.741    38.40739048 1307.959
32.22654081 1262.083    37.58541025 1272.879    38.64167185 1306.284
32.42192776 1262.978    37.81328759 1265.619    38.87595323 1301.775
32.61731471 1263.02     38.04116494 1266.175    39.11023461 1314.69
32.81240152 1258.545    38.26869224 1270.528    39.3441561  1309.956
33.00778847 1265.995    38.49656959 1267.736    39.57843748 1307.676
33.20317541 1262.967    38.72444693 1265.208    39.81271885 1305.026
33.39856236 1267.341    38.95232428 1262.028    40.04700023 1303.623
33.59364917 1264.786    39.17985158 1267.735    40.28092172 1297.713
33.78903612 1262.82     39.40772893 1269.511    40.5152031  1297.501
33.98442307 1268.272    39.63560627 1274.675    40.74948447 1295.841
34.17981002 1261.765    39.86348362 1266.729    40.98376585 1292.558
34.37489683 1262.576    40.09101092 1268.411    41.21768734 1292.379
34.57028378 1258.144    40.31888827 1271.119    41.45196872 1293.682
34.76567072 1261.936    40.54676561 1270.274    41.68625009 1290.106
34.96105767 1266.564    40.77464296 1278.749    41.92053147 1279.904
35.15614448 1266.756    41.00217026 1280.645    42.15445297 1282.822
35.35153143 1267.157    41.23004761 1268.709    42.38873434 1274.595
35.54691838 1259.672    41.45792495 1272.349    42.62301572 1281.033
35.74230533 1268.914    41.6858023  1277.417    42.85729709 1283.563
35.93739214 1254.852    41.9133296  1285.868    43.09121859 1284.36
36.13277909 1257.348    42.14120694 1284.004    43.32549996 1280.907
36.32816603 1257.96     42.36908429 1295.894    43.55978134 1283.262
36.52355298 1247.64     42.59696164 1279.08     43.79406271 1274.061
36.71863979 1256.518    42.82448894 1292.385    44.02798421 1279.032
36.91402674 1250.124    43.05236628 1295.563    44.26226558 1281.568
37.10941369 1247.72     43.28024363 1293.011    44.49654696 1284.691
37.30480064 1244.501    43.50812097 1295.585    44.73082833 1287.341
37.49988745 1262.397    43.73564828 1297.248    44.96474983 1280.797
37.6952744  1267.534    43.96352562 1296.157    45.19903121 1286.481
37.89066134 1255.294    44.19140297 1304.498    45.43331258 1280.994
38.08604829 1254.956    44.41928031 1297.142    45.66759396 1286.02
38.28113511 1261.282    44.64680762 1289.692    45.90151545 1279.334
38.47652205 1267.596    44.87468496 1294.326    46.13579683 1265.482
38.671909   1256.404    45.10256231 1295.012    46.3700782  1272.581
38.86729595 1266.605    45.33043965 1293.822    46.60435958 1261.219
39.06238276 1265.015    45.55796696 1290.819    46.83828107 1262.109
39.25776971 1259.04     45.7858443  1285.323    47.07256245 1263.576
39.45315665 1262.89     46.01372165 1283.232    47.30684382 1259.797
39.6485436  1250.507    46.24159899 1289.957    47.5411252  1266.345
39.84363042 1253.144    46.4691263  1291.784    47.77504669 1256.556
40.03901736 1256.887    46.69700364 1286.12     48.00932807 1258.346
40.23440431 1253.23     46.92488099 1282.41     48.24360944 1265.127
40.42979126 1243.157    47.15275833 1283.986    48.47789082 1271.631
40.62487807 1247.459    47.38028563 1281.936    48.71181232 1270.644
40.82026502 1236.372    47.60816298 1281.947    48.94609369 1270.149
41.01565197 1240.389    47.83604032 1279.841    49.18037507 1271.337
41.21103891 1241.786    48.06391767 1273.789    49.41465644 1271.843
41.40612573 1243.51     48.29144497 1280.297    49.64857794 1272.989
41.60151267 1240.374    48.51932232 1282.257    49.88285931 1272.105
41.79689962 1239.282    48.74719966 1274.528    50.11714069 1259.891
41.99228657 1237.781    48.97507701 1275.872    50.35142206 1265.185
42.18737338 1227.766    49.20260431 1281.407    50.58534356 1261.342
42.38276033 1221.885    49.43048166 1272.137    50.81962493 1262.537
42.57814728 1230.133    49.658359   1272.458    51.05390631 1254.1
42.77353422 1228.39     49.88623635 1276.477    51.28818768 1250.648
42.96862104 1231.625    50.11376365 1276.906    51.52210918 1253.437
43.16400798 1222.88     50.341641   1275.092    51.75639056 1252.758
43.35939493 1222.077    50.56951834 1270.251    51.99067193 1243.454
43.55478188 1205.827    50.79739569 1273.155    52.22495331 1248.885
43.74986869 1215        51.02492299 1267.187    52.4588748  1240.177
43.94525564 1206.464    51.25280034 1263.293    52.69315618 1242.195
44.14064259 1213.185    51.48067768 1272.024    52.92743755 1233.923
44.33602953 1207.712    51.70855503 1271.514    53.16171893 1228.824
44.53111635 1208.891    51.93608233 1275.289    53.39564042 1232.582
44.72650329 1204.577    52.16395968 1270.977    53.6299218  1232.048
44.92189024 1212.341    52.39183702 1282.892    53.86420317 1232.551
45.11727719 1206.814    52.61971437 1278.11     54.09848455 1229.491
45.312364   1199.861    52.84724167 1280.85     54.33240604 1234
45.50775095 1191.17     53.07511901 1277.2      54.56668742 1235.219
45.7031379  1195.391    53.30299636 1281.152    54.80096879 1237.032
45.89852484 1196.429    53.5308737  1283.686    55.03525017 1237.628
46.09361166 1201.87     53.75840101 1280.803    55.26917167 1237.014
46.2889986  1202.308    53.98627835 1282.1      55.50345304 1247.458
46.48438555 1199.01     54.2141557  1278.739    55.73773442 1254.408
46.6797725  1191.272    54.44203304 1270.621    55.97201579 1262.279
46.87485931 1185.373    54.66956035 1281.76     56.20593729 1268.596
47.07024626 1182.136    54.89743769 1280.316    56.44021866 1268.195
47.26563321 1178.456    55.12531504 1276.358    56.67450004 1274.734
47.46102015 1188.129    55.35319238 1283.118    56.90878141 1286.824
47.65610697 1189.636    55.58071969 1281.043    57.14270291 1291.14
47.85149391 1193.698    55.80859703 1282.239    57.37698428 1300.478
48.04688086 1185.979    56.03647438 1276.929    57.61126566 1300.545
48.24226781 1191.271    56.26435172 1289.537    57.84554703 1313.551
48.43735462 1192.961    56.49187903 1296.965    58.07946853 1312.275
48.63274157 1190.991    56.71975637 1298.647    58.31374991 1320.119
48.82812852 1185.052    56.94763372 1312.614    58.54803128 1318.936
49.02351546 1191.066    57.17551106 1315.535    58.78231266 1330.281
49.21860228 1190.043    57.40303836 1320.54     59.01623415 1327.708
49.41398923 1186.524    57.63091571 1329.055    59.25051553 1326.495
49.60937617 1180.292    57.85879306 1320.027    59.4847969  1341.372
49.80476312 1182.784    58.0866704  1325.3      59.71907828 1348.28
49.99984993 1179.376    58.3141977  1314.137    59.95299977 1357.462
50.19523688 1176.451    58.54207505 1316.386    60.18728115 1359.423
50.39062383 1175.014    58.76995239 1316.119    60.42156252 1365.734
50.58601077 1175.495    58.99782974 1318.764    60.6558439  1370.08
50.78109759 1174.257    59.22535704 1334.29     60.88976539 1372.876
50.97648454 1187.144    59.45323439 1334.159    61.12404677 1387.1
51.17187148 1185.775    59.68111173 1356.101    61.35832815 1396.225
51.36725843 1188.639    59.90898908 1350.83     61.59260952 1407.736
51.56234524 1185.028    60.13651638 1354.13     61.82653102 1415.577
51.75773219 1186.037    60.36439373 1367.271    62.06081239 1435.526
51.95311914 1190.458    60.59227107 1375.902    62.29509377 1451.533
52.14850609 1188.198    60.82014842 1394.84     62.52937514 1471.518
52.3435929  1185.897    61.04767572 1401.792    62.76329664 1495.467
52.53897985 1188.896    61.27555307 1407.609    62.99757801 1519.875
52.73436679 1181.076    61.50343041 1422.148    63.23185939 1545.549
52.92975374 1177.398    61.73130776 1431.899    63.46614076 1568.987
53.12484055 1179.343    61.95883506 1437.025    63.70006226 1599.854
53.3202275  1178.094    62.18671241 1448.6      63.93434363 1636.341
53.51561445 1182.618    62.41458975 1457.882    64.16862501 1657.11
53.7110014  1178.708    62.6424671  1463.948    64.40290638 1679.032
53.90608821 1179.489    62.8699944  1471.205    64.63682788 1720.26
54.10147516 1180.855    63.09787174 1479.598    64.87110926 1750.025
54.2968621  1180.77     63.32574909 1479.287    65.10539063 1774.429
54.49224905 1180.362    63.55362644 1475.932    65.33967201 1792.277
54.68733586 1172.25     63.78115374 1490.668    65.5735935  1808.372
54.88272281 1178.812    64.00903108 1500.34     65.80787488 1830.696
55.07810976 1176.289    64.23690843 1510.222    66.04215625 1852.178
55.27349671 1180.064    64.46478577 1530.78     66.27643763 1868.419
55.46858352 1177.502    64.69231308 1528.691    66.51035912 1887.312
55.66397047 1180.039    64.92019042 1528.815    66.7446405  1907.991
55.85935741 1174.591    65.14806777 1531.351    66.97892187 1917
56.05474436 1179.807    65.37594511 1547.44     67.21320325 1917.319
56.25013131 1181.26     65.60382246 1541.742    67.44748462 1931.076
56.44521812 1183.912    65.83134976 1550.731    67.68140612 1935.605
56.64060507 1183.677    66.05922711 1554.437    67.9156875  1951.967
56.83599202 1180.237    66.28710445 1560.202    68.14996887 1959.203
57.03137896 1182.418    66.5149818  1576.801    68.38425025 1974.814
57.22646578 1193.587    66.7425091  1579.647    68.61817174 1975.935
57.42185272 1195.957    66.97038645 1594.158    68.85245312 1982.103
57.61723967 1200.535    67.19826379 1604.523    69.08673449 1984.685
57.81262662 1203.053    67.42614114 1623.636    69.32101587 1996.127
58.00771343 1207.191    67.65366844 1640.598    69.55493736 2002.657
58.20310038 1216.577    67.88154579 1644.387    69.78921874 2016.813
58.39848733 1218.874    68.10942313 1662.07     70.02350011 2027.398
58.59387427 1222.839    68.33730048 1677.048    70.25778149 2033.911
58.78896109 1235.142    68.56482778 1690.482    70.49170298 2055.863
58.98434803 1231.07     68.79270512 1686.96     70.72598436 2074.211
59.17973498 1230.983    69.02058247 1696.465    70.96026573 2081.649
59.37512193 1239.605    69.24845982 1707.292    71.19454711 2100.683
59.57020874 1242.955    69.47598712 1723.958    71.42846861 2096.335
59.76559569 1249.099    69.70386446 1720.939    71.66274998 2105.564
59.96098264 1253.643    69.93174181 1735.843    71.89703136 2113.44
60.15636958 1255.775    70.15961915 1737.126    72.13131273 2110.921
60.3514564  1261.427    70.38714646 1751.79     72.36523423 2127.123
60.54684335 1257.901    70.6150238  1764.772    72.5995156  2122.038
60.74223029 1264.37     70.84290115 1784.799    72.83379698 2142.254
60.93761724 1268.466    71.07077849 1804.148    73.06807835 2146.934
61.13270405 1276.994    71.2983058  1822.835    73.30199985 2162.755
61.328091   1276.724    71.52618314 1840.102    73.53628122 2172.515
61.52347795 1288.212    71.75406049 1860.876    73.7705626  2175.381
61.71886489 1285.771    71.98193783 1891.899    74.00484397 2188.528
61.91395171 1285.589    72.20946514 1898.153    74.23876547 2199.969
62.10933866 1293.058    72.43734248 1915.565    74.47304685 2220.001
62.3047256  1296.144    72.66521983 1926.155    74.70732822 2224.626
62.50011255 1298.43     72.89309717 1923.384    74.9416096  2233.806
62.69519936 1301.872    73.12062447 1915.506    75.17553109 2245.535
62.89058631 1296.875    73.34850182 1939.946    75.40981247 2254.988
63.08597326 1289.286    73.57637917 1955.845    75.64409384 2271.927
63.28136021 1290.178    73.80425651 1963.435    75.87837522 2283.161
63.47644702 1298.047    74.03178381 1965.297    76.11229671 2289.592
63.67183397 1296.653    74.25966116 1997.774    76.34657809 2301.178
63.86722091 1298.865    74.4875385  2016.366    76.58085946 2301.462
64.06260786 1309.23     74.71541585 2021.985    76.81514084 2293.286
64.25769467 1308.123    74.94294315 2046.057    77.04906233 2279.317
64.45308162 1313.581    75.1708205  2078.271    77.28334371 2274.366
64.64846857 1325.644    75.39869784 2092.549    77.51762509 2258.078
64.84385552 1326.668    75.62657519 2102.894    77.75190646 2232.809
65.03894233 1329.844    75.85410249 2136.226    77.98582796 2219.475
65.23432928 1338.079    76.08197984 2147.428    78.22010933 2204.092
65.42971622 1331.554    76.30985718 2157.531    78.45439071 2181.507
65.62510317 1340.53     76.53773453 2156.997    78.68867208 2154.852
65.82018998 1335.017    76.76526183 2156.958    78.92259358 2145.615
66.01557693 1336.335    76.99313918 2140.064    79.15687495 2123.053
66.21096388 1343.65     77.22101652 2124.298    79.39115633 2107.074
66.40635083 1351.036    77.44889387 2117.136    79.6254377  2099.833
66.60143764 1357.288    77.67642117 2099.826    79.8593592  2091.036
66.79682459 1365.56     77.90429852 2084.747    80.09364057 2096.691
66.99221153 1343.035    78.13217586 2063.832    80.32792195 2118.663
67.18759848 1359.641    78.36005321 2057.571    80.56220332 2120.531
67.38268529 1358.499    78.58758051 2053.788    80.79612482 2136.495
67.57807224 1349.543    78.81545785 2049.701    81.0304062  2140.338
67.77345919 1349.057    79.0433352  2040.784    81.26468757 2142.352
67.96884614 1357.421    79.27121255 2036.142    81.49896895 2145.631
68.16393295 1355.127    79.49873985 2031.427    81.73289044 2144.712
68.3593199  1362.27     79.72661719 2039.564    81.96717182 2121.603
68.55470684 1360.612    79.95449454 2045.726    82.20145319 2108.833
68.75009379 1361.997    80.18237188 2035.744    82.43573457 2097.616
68.94518061 1376.965    80.40989919 2046.304    82.66965606 2083.577
69.14056755 1381.501    80.63777653 2050.502    82.90393744 2073.309
69.3359545  1387.866    80.86565388 2056.951    83.13821881 2065.762
69.53134145 1397.778    81.09353122 2048.294    83.37250019 2065.044
69.72642826 1405.987    81.32105853 2041.393    83.60642168 2064.912
69.92181521 1412.51     81.54893587 2027.322    83.84070306 2075.443
70.11720215 1409.658    81.77681322 2029.718    84.07498444 2083.698
70.3125891  1425.674    82.00469056 2018.92     84.30926581 2087.095
70.50767592 1422.538    82.23221787 2019.598    84.54318731 2089.336
70.70306286 1413.651    82.46009521 2012.278    84.77746868 2098.657
70.89844981 1427.284    82.68797256 2006.041    85.01175006 2120.575
71.09383676 1423.044    82.9158499  2007.608    85.24603143 2149.515
71.28892357 1424.464    83.14337721 1996.632    85.47995293 2160.771
71.48431052 1427.781    83.37125455 2000.753    85.7142343  2182.059
71.67969747 1428.257    83.5991319  1992.076    85.94851568 2213.923
71.87508441 1423.692    83.82700924 2011.199    86.18279705 2230.813
72.07017123 1430.871    84.05453654 2022.255    86.41671855 2251.498
72.26555817 1437.886    84.28241389 2037.361    86.65099992 2267.747
72.46094512 1442.134    84.51029123 2043.161    86.8852813  2285.884
72.65633207 1454.257    84.73816858 2061.688    87.11956267 2292.733
72.85141888 1465.162    84.96569588 2077.299    87.35348417 2301.616
73.04680583 1486.434    85.19357323 2108.792    87.58776555 2314.968
73.24219278 1510.091    85.42145057 2112.299    87.82204692 2322.847
73.43757972 1541.27     85.64932792 2141.01     88.0563283  2346.1
73.63266654 1576.056    85.87685522 2152.631    88.29024979 2366.663
73.82805348 1600.854    86.10473257 2170.012    88.52453117 2395.322
74.02344043 1627.349    86.33260991 2188.086    88.75881254 2409.828
74.21882738 1663.645    86.56048726 2195.611    88.99309392 2428.756
74.41391419 1694.601    86.78801456 2190.323    89.22701541 2441.494
74.60930114 1708.452    87.01589191 2215.415    89.46129679 2435.314
74.80468809 1728.447    87.24376925 2212.544    89.69557816 2410.859
75.00007503 1767.046    87.4716466  2215.644    89.92985954 2382.735
75.19516185 1787.85     87.6991739  2226.579    90.16378104 2356.402
75.39054879 1818.605    87.92705125 2211.397    90.39806241 2319.247
75.58593574 1844.125    88.15492859 2205.946    90.63234379 2281.804
75.78132269 1851.533    88.38280594 2204.915    90.86662516 2252.137
75.9764095  1878.14     88.61033324 2190.382    91.10054666 2220.047
76.17179645 1890.373    88.83821059 2176.404    91.33482803 2194.386
76.3671834  1896.27     89.06608793 2161.429    91.56910941 2176.124
76.56257034 1908.274    89.29396528 2163.168    91.80339078 2181.918
76.75765716 1915.822    89.52149258 2162.387    92.03731228 2189.776
76.9530441  1954.387    89.74936992 2150.162    92.27159365 2216.542
77.14843105 1960.739    89.97724727 2147.05     92.50587503 2229.851
77.343818   1981.194    90.20512461 2141.054    92.7401564  2251.147
77.53890481 2022.806    90.43265192 2132.501    92.9740779  2267.448
77.73429176 2044.99     90.66052926 2130.861    93.20835927 2272.591
77.92967871 2074.013    90.88840661 2118.505    93.44264065 2257.713
78.12506565 2102.402    91.11628395 2122.159    93.67692202 2236.556
78.32015247 2137.748    91.34381126 2139.659    93.91084352 2209.66
78.51553942 2152.239    91.5716886  2138.118    94.1451249  2176.827
78.71092636 2160.393    91.79956595 2148.866    94.37940627 2134.504
78.90631331 2170.924    92.02744329 2156.126    94.61368765 2092.327
79.10140012 2184.47     92.2549706  2140.743    94.84760914 2043.45
79.29678707 2193.477    92.48284794 2122.816    95.08189052 1998.126
79.49217402 2224.39     92.71072529 2130.157    95.31617189 1941.972
79.68756096 2231.489    92.93860263 2121.949    95.55045327 1893.985
79.88264778 2236.18     93.16612994 2117.948    95.78437476 1850.962
80.07803473 2237.527    93.39400728 2102.601    96.01865614 1822.539
80.27342167 2231.84     93.62188463 2081.846    96.25293751 1783.319
80.46880862 2250.712    93.84976197 2053.464    96.48721889 1764.87
80.66389543 2260.198    94.07728927 2034.901    96.72114039 1748.792
80.85928238 2255.465    94.30516662 2027.98     96.95542176 1727.581
81.05466933 2262.62     94.53304397 2006.726    97.18970314 1694.929
81.25005628 2273.95     94.76092131 1992.966    97.42398451 1669.758
81.44514309 2257.958    94.98844861 1969.021    97.65790601 1636.053
81.64053004 2245.562    95.21632596 1952.287    97.89218738 1608.15
81.83591698 2225.173    95.4442033  1936.346    98.12646876 1576.101
82.03130393 2198.592    95.67208065 1922.252    98.36075013 1515.692
82.22639074 2179.263    95.89960795 1874.425    98.59467163 1488.061
82.42177769 2148.892    96.1274853  1853.664    98.828953   1448.425
82.61716464 2116.719    96.35536264 1831.384    99.06323438 1397.268
82.81255159 2100.717    96.58323999 1794.029    99.29751575 1355.717
83.0076384  2090.508    96.81076729 1758.89     99.53143725 1329.739
83.20302535 2065.061    97.03864464 1731.598    99.76571862 1296.793
83.39841229 2050.854    97.26652198 1713.487    100 1257.241
83.59379924 2040.492    97.49439933 1677.765        
83.78888605 2040.322    97.72192663 1674.917        
83.984273   2035.772    97.94980398 1662.389        
84.17965995 2044.099    98.17768132 1642.568        
84.3750469  2044.25     98.40555867 1633.19     
84.57043384 2050.526    98.63343601 1617.934        
84.76552066 2052.062    98.86096332 1611.145        
84.9609076  2061.378    99.08884066 1595.799        
85.15629455 2075.489    99.31671801 1573.702        
85.3516815  2096.737    99.54459535 1534.946        
85.54676831 2092.632    99.77212265 1504.292        
85.74215526 2109.604    100 1461.003        
85.93754221 2141.326                
86.13292915 2144.713                
86.32801597 2160.355                
86.52340291 2169.707                
86.71878986 2194.609                
86.91417681 2205.215                
87.10926362 2223.762                
87.30465057 2230.832                
87.50003752 2229.607                
87.69542446 2246.726                
87.89051128 2253.896                
88.08589822 2248.059                
88.28128517 2257.528                
88.47667212 2258.268                
88.67175893 2235.478                
88.86714588 2225.722                
89.06253283 2221.924                
89.25791977 2208.82             
89.45300659 2188.229                
89.64839354 2178.863                
89.84378048 2191.26             
90.03916743 2180.9              
90.23425424 2178.216                
90.42964119 2181.684                
90.62502814 2171.685                
90.82041508 2165.909                
91.0155019  2164.717                
91.21088885 2146.029                
91.40627579 2154.498                
91.60166274 2159.514                
91.79674955 2150.546                
91.9921365  2152.278                
92.18752345 2160.359                
92.3829104  2136.148                
92.57799721 2125.964                
92.77338416 2124.083                
92.9687711  2116.051                
93.16415805 2123.932                
93.35924486 2103.822                
93.55463181 2072.381                
93.75001876 2056.456                
93.94540571 2027.103                
94.14049252 2000.528                
94.33587947 1960.458                
94.53126641 1931.848                
94.72665336 1908.658                
94.92174017 1872.342                
95.11712712 1862.123                
95.31251407 1816.906                
95.50790102 1797.595                
95.70298783 1773.479                
95.89837478 1748.537                
96.09376172 1725.848                
96.28914867 1689.956                
96.48423548 1660.641                
96.67962243 1633.764                
96.87500938 1618.012                
97.07039633 1597.76             
97.26548314 1584.849                
97.46087009 1579.388                
97.65625703 1568.659                
97.85164398 1557.276                
98.0467308  1546.187                
98.24211774 1534.488                
98.43750469 1510.142                
98.63289164 1491.203                
98.82797845 1471.416                
99.0233654  1431.345                
99.21875234 1403.688                
99.41413929 1368.222                
99.60922611 1326.034                
99.80461305 1291.5              
100 1262.928
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).